# Asset paths in express

Tags: node.js, express

I used the following to declare my asset paths in my node app:

```
app.use("/styles", express.static(__dirname + '/public/styles'));
app.use("/images", express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));
app.use("/script", express.static(__dirname + '/public/script'));
```

...but it seems to be adding the url path (e.g. '/search') in the asset path which then passes it through the logic. All paths are relative for portability - how do I avoid this?

Thanks in advance... :)

James

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just do this and you'll be done:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```